# How can I tell if two braids are equal?

Tags: group-theory, braid-groups

I was reading [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braid_group#Basic_properties). 
 In it they claim that

\begin{equation}\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_1 = \sigma_2\sigma_1\sigma_2\end{equation}

> Here $\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \sigma_3$ represent the 4 generators of the braid group $B_4$

I went verify this on paper and I was having a hard time, so I went and got out a piece of string and tried it.  Sure enough it is in fact true, if you apply $\sigma_1^-$ to each side you get:

\begin{equation}\sigma_1\sigma_2 = \sigma_2\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_1^-\end{equation}

And I was able to convince myself, via physical manipulation that

\begin{equation}\sigma_2\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_1^-=\sigma_1\sigma_2 \end{equation}

However this doesn't sit well with me.  Having to verify if two braids are equal by playing around with string each time seems quite cumbersome.  I tried the other example on the wiki as well as a few ones I made up (which all turned out to be unequal) but I wasn't seeing any pattern.

What ways are there for determining the equality of two braids?  I don't necessarily want a closed form, an algorithm or a rule of thumb will suffice as far as I am concerned.

Comment: Do you know Artin's relations ? This is the relation you wrote + the obvious one (($\sigma_i$ commutes with $\sigma_j$ if$|i-j| > 1$.)

Comment: @N.H. I was not familiar with Artin's relations.  Can equality be checked by repeated applications of these relations?

Comment: Exactly, take two words $w_1, w_2$ and try to see if $w_1w_2^{-1}$ is the trivial word. For this, you can reduce the lenght of the word using the relation of Artin, but I don't know how hard it is in practice. But for small $n$ it should be easy.

Comment: This isn't particularly easy I am afraid. There are normal forms, such as the Garside normal form, that can be used to solve the word problem.

Comment: @N.H. Could you point me to a source explaining what Artin's relations are precisely?  I haven't been able to find much information on them myself.

Comment: The generators are $\sigma_i$ and the relation are $\sigma_i \sigma_{i+1} \sigma_i = \sigma_{i+1} \sigma_i \sigma_{i+1}$ for all $i$ and $\sigma_i \sigma_j = \sigma_j \sigma_i$ if $ |i - j | > 1$. I don't know a reference but googling "braid group, Artin relations" should gives you a source.

Comment: The relation $\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_1=\sigma_2\sigma_1\sigma_2$ should be obvious just by looking at the two braids - it is, after all, just the type III [Reidemeister move](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reidemeister_move). However, determining whether two arbitrary words in the generators are equal is not something you should expect to be easy.

Answer (score 1):

The braid groups are known to be linear, so you can work with a faithful matrix representation such as the [Lawrence-Krammer representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence%E2%80%93Krammer_representation). Then you can just compute some matrices and check whether they are equal.